# Set cache-control in HTTP headers for UI Components (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, cache, performance, uicomponent

The main delay in Magento page loading into client browser is the js/html files summary delay. So, my homepage is loading about 9 sec., DOMContentLoaded = 1.75 sec. (PHP generated HTML) and all other time is for CSS/IMG/JS/HTML loading.

I see that HTTP headers contain "Cache-Control:no-cache" in the responses for JS & HTML files. Can I set up "Cache-Control" headers for these files on Magento level or web server level (I use apache2)?

[image]

Comment: I had disabled cache in my browser (checkbox in the top of the screenshot). Loading time is about 6.5 sec with enabled cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `pub/static/.htaccess` file on your magento instance? If no then you can find it [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/pub/static/.htaccess).

You also need mod_expires enabled on your apache. If it's not then enable it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The value no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 for Cache-Control that you see only applies to browser caches, which instructs Magento HTML to not be cached by them.

That Cache-Control that you're seeing is emitted by Varnish VCL. This is fine, and this value does not make the Varnish cache less effective. This is only meant for browsers.

Varnish will use a different Cache-Control, emitted by Magento itself. Varnish cache lifetime depends on the TTL setting you have in the Magento backend.

You can access Magento HTTP headers (by doing curl against the proper port) directly and you'll see that the Cache-Control emitted by it is different, typically one day:

Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400. This is what Varnish sees and uses to define how long it caches public pages.

To recap:

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 is to be expected unless you're checking Magento headers directly
To cache things longer by Varnish, adjust the TTL in Magento settings